# Making radio button text bigger

Tags: html, css, web

```css
.q1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="a" value="" class="q1"><i>Plant Island</i><br />
```

I am trying to make the size of the text next to the radio button bigger but the font size does not change. I have also tried using input{} for the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Move `q1` class to the `i` tag.

```css
.q1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="a" value=""><i class="q1">Plant Island</i><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the button, not the text.

BTW, the appearance of form-related elements is controlled by browsers, css is very limited for them, changing the font of input takes no effects.

```css
.q1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="q1">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="dummy">
    Plant Island
  </label>
</div>
```